# Type mismatch. cannot from String to Student in java

Tags: java, types, type-conversion, type-mismatch

A total noob question. I'm trying to convert from `Scanner` to `Student` type. It's part of my academic assignment and so, I'm not allowed to change return type of `getStudent()` method to String. Any inputs? Thanks.

```
public Student getStudent() {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    Student name = sc.nextLine();
    return name;
}
```

Comment: I don't think you are converting `Scanner` to `Student`. You are converting `String` to `Student`

Comment: yeah, you're right. thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why you do this is probably because the `Student` class has only a `name` field. You think you can just return a name to pretend that is a student, don't you? But that isn't how Java works. Java's type system is static, explicit and safe. That means you can't just cheat Java, you must specify the *correct* type.

Now if your `Student` class doesn't have a constructor yet, add a constructor. Maybe something like this:

```
public Student (String name) {
    this.name = name;
    // If you have other fields, assign them here.
}
```

Now in your method, you remove `return name;` and replace it with

```
return new Student (name);
```

Conclusion of your mistake:

`String` and another class are completely different types. Although the `Student` class only has a field of type `String`.